# In Matthew 10:10 - What does "τροφῆς" specifically refer to?

Tags: greek, matthew

**We read a variety of translations for "τροφῆς" from the Gospel of Matthew - Chapter 10, verse 10** :

[NIV]
"no bag for the journey or extra shirt or sandals or a staff, for the worker is worth his **keep**."

[NKJV]
"nor bag for your journey, nor two tunics, nor sandals, nor staffs; for a worker is worthy of his **food**."

[NASB]
or a bag for your journey, or even two tunics, or sandals, or a staff; for the worker is deserving of his **support**.

[GNT]
10 do not carry a beggar's bag for the trip or an extra shirt or shoes or a walking stick. Workers should be given what they **need**.

---

When searching for an accurate meaning,  **τροφῆς** appears to be : "food", "keep", "support", or essential "needs" for survival. - **What does "τροφῆς" specifically refer to?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://biblehub.com/greek/5160.htm

Strong's Concordance

> trophé: nourishment, **food**
> Original Word: τροφή, ῆς, ἡ
> Part of Speech: Noun, Feminine
> Transliteration: trophé
> Phonetic Spelling: (trof-ay')
> Definition: nourishment, food
> Usage: food, nourishment, maintenance.

NAS Exhaustive Concordance

> nourishment, food
> NASB Translation
> enough* (1), **food** (13), meals (1), support (1).

Thayer's Greek Lexicon

> τροφή, τροφῆς, ἡ (τρέφω, 2 perfect τέτροφα), **food**, nourishment: Matthew 3:4; Matthew 6:25; Matthew 10:10; Matthew 24:45; Luke 12:23; John 4:8; Acts 2:46; Acts 9:19; Acts 14:17; Acts 27:33f, 36, 38; James 2:15; of the food of the mind, i. e. the substance of instruction, Hebrews 5:12, 14. (Tragg., Xenophon, Plato, and following; the Sept. for לֶחֶם, אֹכֶל, מָזון, etc.)

What does "τροφῆς" specifically refer to?

All 3 sources point concretely to food.

Let's look at the context.

> Matthew 10:9 “Do not get any gold or silver or copper to take with you in your belts— 10no bag for the journey or extra shirt or sandals or a staff, for the worker is worth his keep. 11Whatever town or village you enter, search there for some worthy person and stay at their house until you leave.

Even though "τροφῆς" humbly refers to food, figuratively the context suggests accommodation and minimal provisions as well.